# location.href not redirecting to user page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a form which is is linked to signup.js which when someone presses the button start chatting it should redirect to user.php in my case it's not working

```
location.href = "user.php";
```

is giving the problem because i get success when i submit  the form.
But it doesn't work. It simply stays on the login page and nothing happens but gives sucess

```
const form = document.querySelector(".signup form"),
continueBtn = form.querySelector(".button input"),
errorText = form.querySelector(".txt-error");

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    //preventing from submitting
}

continueBtn.onclick = () =>{

   // AJAX code refernce w3schools
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //object created
   xhr.open("POST", "php/signup.php", true);
   xhr.onload = () =>{
       if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
           if(xhr.status === 200){
               let data = xhr.response;
               if(data == "success"){
                    location.href = "user.php";
               }else{
                    errorText.textContent = data;
                    errorText.style.display = "block"; 
              }
           }
       }
    }
    // send form data to php through ajax
    let formData = new FormData(form);  //obj created
    xhr.send(formData); //sending data to php
}
```

These are my codes any help will be appreciated.  What I am doing is that when the user clicks the submit button an ajax request is being executed to target php script which logs in the user and if user is logged in successfully then echoes back the message "login_successful" to the ajax request. By using `if` statement I check whether the message is "login_successful" else display the error.

If the message is "login_successful" the script redirects the user to the new page 'user.php' by using

Comment: What about it isn't working? Is it redirecting anywhere? Check the developer console and see if there are any messages there

Comment: heyy, no messages i tried using window.open but still the same, but the database and everything else its working

Comment: its not redirecting anywhere

Comment: Are you getting the `errorText`?

Comment: Are you sure `xhr.status` is returning `200`? Try placing a `debugger` and step through the code with the browser.

Comment: Are there any messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: no messages in the console and no error - text

Comment: My guess, you do not have a 200. Add debugging and see what is happening in the code.

Comment: crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. ----- after debugging this is the msg i get

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
    at (program) (undefined:5496:1)                                                                                        this is what i get when i debug it

Comment: Hey I found my solution.                             ,,` let data = xhr.response;
               if(data == "success"){
                    location.href = "user.php";.`.          The variable data had white space, so I had to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` variable is selected with `.signup form`, which will find the first `<form>` element within the first element with a `signup` class.  For example:

```html
<div class = "signup">
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Presumably, you have a form with the class `signup`, so you want the selector `form.signup`

Once you select the correct element, your `form.onsubmit` listener should work.

The same goes for your `continueBtn` selector - right now it's selecting an `<input>` element inside another element with the class `button`.  Presumably you want the selector `input.button`.

Comment: `<div class = "form signup">                                                                                                        
    <form></form>`                                                                                                                              this is how i have used the classes

Comment: Then you want to select a `form` which is _adjacent_ to `.signup`.  So: `.signup + form`